# How to Plot Vertical Asymptote

Tags: plotting

How can I plot the vertical asymptote `x=3` for this function:
`f(x)=Log2(x-3)`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Plot[Log[2, (x - 3)], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}]
```

Comment: I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions. 2) Take [the tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the check mark sign!

Comment: Look up `InfiniteLine[]`.

Answer (score 1):

A first thing that comes to mind

```
Plot[{Log[2, (x - 3)]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}, Epilog -> Line[{{3, -3}, {3, 3}}]]
```

which gives

[image]

### Edit

As suggested by @J.M., infinite line is better option because it scales with the plot.

```
Plot[{Log[2, (x - 3)]}, {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}, 
 Epilog -> InfiniteLine[{{3, -3}, {3, 3}}], GridLines -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much but could you please explain what this computation means? PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, Automatic}, Epilog -> Line[{{3, -3}, {3, 3}}]]

Comment: Please first read the links in the comment I have left to your original answer. Familiarize yourself with [Mathematica help](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/). I know it can be very difficult to find a function that does something, but once someone shows you that it should be very easy to read help, particularly as in this case, [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html?q=Epilog) is built-in `Option`. There are great resources on this site for beginners. You can start with discussion on [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/34848)

Answer (score 1):

**ParametricPlot**

```
ParametricPlot[{{x, Log[2, (x - 3)]}, {3, Rescale[x, {-10, 10}, {-5, 3}]}}, {x, -10, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-5, 3}}]
```

[image]

**GridLines**

```
Plot[Log[2, x - 3], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-5, 3}}, 
 GridLines -> {{{3, Directive[Thick, Red]}}, None}]
```

[image]

If your plot has horizontal `GridLines` (say, `Range[10]`), re-style the horizontal grid line at `3` using

```
 GridLines -> {Range[10] /. 3 -> {3, Directive[Thick, Red]},  Automatic}]
```

to get

[image]